# Having multiple x3d files on a website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a website that displays multiple x3d files, the code that I have only shows one file immediately (shown below)

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <title>Heritage Together</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.x3dom.org/download/x3dom.js'>    </script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'   href='http://www.x3dom.org/download/x3dom.css'/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Heritage Together</h1>
    <p>
        This page will show any two models and display them side by side
    </p>
    <script>
    function redNose()
    {
      if(document.getElementById('Deer__MA_Nose').getAttribute('diffuseColor')!= '1 0 0')
         document.getElementById('Deer__MA_Nose').setAttribute('diffuseColor', '1 0 0');
        else
          document.getElementById('Deer__MA_Nose').setAttribute('diffuseColor', '0 0 0');
    }
    </script>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Areas</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">area1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">area2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">area3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Types of models</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">model1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">model2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">model3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">model4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">model5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <x3d width='500px' height='500px'>
            <scene>
                    <viewpoint position="-1.94639 1.79771 -2.89271"   orientation="0.03886 0.99185 0.12133 3.75685"></viewpoint>
                    <Inline nameSpaceName="Deer" mapDEFToID="true"
                            onclick='redNose();' url="Deer.x3d" />
            </scene>
        </x3d>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the css file that I have is as follows

```
ul {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
li ul {
    display: none;
}
ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    background: #1e7c9a;
    margin-left: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
ul li a:hover {
background: #3b3b3b;
}
li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
li:hover li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 11px;
}
li:hover a { background: #3b3b3b; }
li:hover li a:hover {
    background: #1e7c9a;
}

body{
   background-color: black;
}

h1{
    color: white;
    text-indent: 600px;
}
p{
      color: white;
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve with this website is to have the x3d models that I have located in the 'areas' drop down menu or the 'types of models' menu. And I want to have the two models that the user chooses to be displayed side by side. The question is, is how do I get the models in the drop down menus and how do I display them

Comment: What's the Question?

Comment: Where do you have the areas and model types defined ?

Comment: The question is, is how do I have the models in the drop down menus and how do I display them

Comment: I have all the models located in the same folder as the HTML folder

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure how you are populating the list of Areas and Models, so lets just use the HTML you have.

We will use the DOM element to populate a list. For this we need to add a unuiqe identifier.

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Areas</a>
        <ul id="area_list">
            <li><a href="#">area1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">area2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">area3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Types of models</a>
        <ul id="model_list">
            <li><a href="#">model1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">model2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">model3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">model4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">model5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see the `ul` elements have ids added to them. This will be the identifyier to see what it's children are.

JS:

```
var areaList = [],
    modelList = [];

function populateLists(){
  alert("running");
    var areaUL = document.getElementById('area_list').children;
    var modelUL = document.getElementById('model_list').children;

    for(var i = 0; i < areaUL.length; i++){
            areaList.push(areaUL[i].children[0].text);
    }
  alert("Area Items : " + areaList.length);
};
```

This will add to the areaList all the area items.. You can see then how to do the same for the models.

I think this is what you're looking for but your question is hard to follow.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j2k7h17r/)

### Few things to note :

This can be made easier, convenient with `jQuery` though not compulsory at all.

If you are using the filesystems listings to populate the list, this will require server side logic to send the data (file listings) to the javascript. There is no native way in Javascript alone to achieve this. (*Excluding `nodeJS` server*)

Comment: The end product that I'm aiming for, is to have a website that has two drop down menus 'Areas' and 'Types of Models' and within these two drop down menus will have all the x3d models that I have, and to display any two models that the user picks and show them side by side. My question is, is how do I load the x3d models into the website and how do I put them in the two drop down menus

Comment: @user3057793 you're going to need some webserver for that, and you have a legend of server side languages to choose from, I can write a `PHP` example for you if that suits ?

Comment: I think they way that I'm going to do it, is to get rid of the drop down menus and show all the models and allow the user to choose two models which will show them side by side